# Creating a lazy hashed iterator

Tags: perl, functional-programming, cpan

In research of this question I peeked at the Iterators chapter in the book Higher Order Perl, and some of the material there was a bit over my head and didn't think necessarily addressed what I specifically want here.

What I mean by lazy hashed iterator is a way to create a structure that would emulate this behavior:

```
%Ds = {
       '1' => 1 .. 20;
       '2' => 21 .. 40;
       '3' => 41 .. 60;
       '4' => 61 .. 80;
       ...
     }
```

Unfortunately, since this is a hash it would not be in order and thus useless in case of very large numbers.

The behavior is this:

```
I have a number. 
I need to compare it with a sequence of ranges and as a result of the comparison the 
code/sub would return another number that is the "key" of that range in case the
number is in that range. (>= with the beginning or <= with the end point of said range)
The "key" of the ranges are numbers from 1..2..3 and so on.
The code/sub will always return for a positive integer no matter how large it is.
```

By implementing this all lazily I mean if there is a way to emulate this behavior and not compute the sequences of ranges with their respective "keys" with every call of the sub or iteration of a loop. Basically compute once.

Yes it's true that I could choose a maximum boundary, hardcode this in a loop and be done with it but the problem is I don't know of how many of these steps I would need in the end.

Is there a way to do this with perl constructs or maybe perhaps there is a CPAN module that offers this kind of behaviour and my simple search of it didn't uncover it.

Here is a piece of code that illustrates what I mean:

```
sub get_nr {
  my $nr = shift;
  my %ds = map {  $a = '1' if /1/ .. /20/;
                  $a = '2' if /21/ .. /40/;
                  $a = '3' if /41/ .. /60/;
                  $a = '4' if /61/ .. /80/;
                  $_ => $a } 1 .. 80;

  while (my ($k, $v) = each %ds) {
     if ( $k == $nr){
     print "number is in range $v \n";
     }
  }
}
```

The output for:

```
 get_nr(4);
 get_nr(15);
 get_nr(22);
 get_nr(45);
```

Is:

```
number is in range 1
number is in range 1
number is in range 2
number is in range 3
```

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your question because you keep taking about wanting a behaviour, but you don't describe any behaviours. (You seem to describe a data structure.) Am I correct to say you want a function called like `$h{$x}` that returns `$x*20-19 .. $x*20`?

Comment: `Ds` is not a Perl variable, it is a bareword. Did you mean `$Ds`?

Comment: Also, this is a typical question that sounds like an XY-problem: Asking a question about the solution instead of the problem you are trying to solve. It would be beneficial to know what problem you are trying to solve using this technique.

Comment: edited with additional information. Please keep in mind that I want to do this lazily, that is the whole point. Otherwise it would be trivial.

Comment: Perhaps you should give an example on what you consider trivial. Are you trying to simply match a number against a number of ranges? Are the ranges mutually exclusive?

Comment: And are the numbers you intend to look up integers, or can they be floats?

Comment: The numbers are positive ints, guaranteed. The intervals don't intersect as shown in the example. Eg: $nr = 25, my hash has to give me 2 from that.

Comment: Ok, I understand your problem now. You say you can solve this easily the hard way, but you are looking for a lazy way. So what do you mean by that? I could solve this in a handful different ways, but I dont know what you have already tried and consider trivial. Your hash is backwards, btw, if you want to look up numbers: `%ds = (1 => 'x', 2 => 'x'...)`

Comment: The keys to values order doesn't really matter. You could probably find ways to make it work out either way. By lazy I mean, the code should be able to handle 25 and 12324 too if it needs to. I have no idea how large the number(s) will be, so I thought that having a solution that only computes as much as it needs in order to make the comparison is in order.

Comment: Yes... unfortunately, there is no way to give you advice here. You're saying: "I want some Perl code that gives me a key when I give it a number. I want it to be able to handle any number." You're going to need to be a *lot* more specific than that. What you are describing is a subroutine, based on some mathematical formula, but that would mean that the best advice I can give is to point you towards `perldoc perlsub` and possibly `perlop` for a list of operators to use.

Comment: I will rephrase my question.

Comment: Edited. Please keep in mind that I am not dead set on a particular data structure or anything like that. I just need to know if there is a way to do what I am intending to do in lazy functional kind of way. Ask away if there are things you do not understand about the behaviour I'm hinting at.

Comment: You just said the same thing again, in a more elaborate way. Let me give you an example: `sub inrange {
 my $num = shift;
 my $dec = int($num / 100);
 my $min = $dec * 100;
 my $max = ($dec + 1) * 100;
 print "$num is between $min and $max";
}` This will calculate mathematically in which range of 100 the number is.

Comment: Somewhat tangential, but what you're describing doesn't sound like an iterator.

Comment: [`Number::Range`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Number%3A%3ARange)?

Comment: I will post some code in a second. TLP your code doesn't implement all of the behaviour.

Comment: Posted some working code in the OP. That is the exact behavior I want only done, sorry for repeating myself, lazily.

Comment: The code @TLP gave does exactly that, except it prints the range instead of the "key" (it can easily be modified to print the key). It also has the added benefits of 1) not requiring you to populate a hash and 2) works for arbitrary values. What about that isn't "lazy" enough for you?

Comment: Yes it does work. Sorry for the total brainfart. TLP you can post the code so I can accept the answer.

Comment: the working code is: sub inrange { my $num = shift; my $dec = int($num / 20) + 1; my $min = $dec * 20; my $max = ($dec + 1) * 20; return $dec; }

Comment: @user3046061 Actually, you need to compensate for edge cases, your old sub had `20 => 1`, where as this will give `20 => 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, the code you seem to want is a very simple subroutine

```
sub get_nr {
    my $nr = shift;
    my $range = int(($nr-1) / 20) + 1;
    return $range;
}
```

You need to compensate for the edge cases, you wanted 20 to return 1, for example, so we need to subtract 1 from the number before dividing it.

If you want to customize further, you might use a variable for the range size, instead of a hard coded number.

Comment: Please also add comments that I was looking at the problem the wrong way, didn't need anything functional etc... Also change sub name to get_range.

Comment: range has to be hardcoded, the example I gave in the OP suggested that.

Comment: @user3046061 You seem a bit hard coded yourself, in your way of thinking. :-) If this solves your question, you should consider accepting an answer.

Comment: It would be more useful for people that stumble upon this and actually need something else.

Comment: @user3046061 I'm sure people can work out whether or not this code is useful to them even without me specifying every detail of our discussion.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
sub get_range_number {
   my ($n) = @_;
   return int(($n-1)/20) + 1;
}

print "$_ is in range ".get_range_number($_)."\n"
   for 4, 15, 22, 45;
```

Comment: PS - Note how the printing is done outside of the function. Priting has nothing to do with determine range numbers.